# How to store an array to PFFile in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've read Parse's tutorial on PFFile, I've search on Google and Stack Overflow. It seems like everyone uses PFFile to store image or String. How can I store array to PFFile? Or is this not possible? I cannot use PFObject as I'll be continuing storing array to PFFile, so PFObject will run out of space quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears PFFile has no property list support built in, but you can use [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/) to convert your array to a property list (as NSData), and create the file using that data.